# Shannon Entropy, prove $H(Wx)=H(x)+\log|\det W|$

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, entropy

I'm doing an essay on ICA (independent component analysis), and I could use some help.

In essence, ICA is an algorithm that minimizes the entropy of $n$ $1$-dimensional random variables, but to show this, I need to prove a lemma which I can't seem to prove:

if $\displaystyle H(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n)=-\int P(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n)\log(P(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n)) \, dy$

(where $P(y_i)$ is the density function of random variable $y_i$ and $y$ is the vector of these random variables)

and if $W$ is some invertible matrix, then $H(Wx)=H(x)+\log|\det W|$.

I got this exercise from the youtube lecture on the topic https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=smibJH-0YGc at around 36:50.

I would greatly appreciate help proving this lemma. The main obscurity I have is that the limits are unspecified.

Comment: You may want to have a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZrSzFZhSKE), or read the second page of [these lecture notes](http://www.math.nyu.edu/faculty/kleeman/infolect5.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

You can find this classical result, e.g., in [*Elements of Information Theory*](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/%7Ecgong821/Wiley.Interscience.Elements.of.Information.Theory.Jul.2006.eBook-DDU.pdf) by Cover and Thomas (Corollary of Theorem 8.6.4).

Consider a random variable $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with density $p_X(x)$, and define another random variable $Y := WX \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Their densities are related by $p_Y(y) = \frac{p_X(x)}{|\det J(x)|}$, where $J(x)$ is the Jacobian of the transformation $x \mapsto y = Wx$, which in this case is $J(x)=W$. Therefore the entropy of $Y$ can be written as

$$
\begin{align*}
h(Y)
&= -\int p_Y(y) \log p_Y(y)~\mathrm{d}y\\
&= -\int \frac{p_X(W^{-1}y)}{|\det W|} \log \frac{p_X(W^{-1}y)}{|\det W|}~\mathrm{d}y\\
&= -\int |\det W| \frac{p_X(x)}{|\det W|} \log\frac{p_X(x)}{|\det W|} ~\mathrm{d}x\\
&= - \int p_X(x) \left(\log (p_X(x) - \log|\det W|\right)~\mathrm{d}x\\
&= - \int p_X(x) \log (p_X(x)~\mathrm{d}x + \int p_X(x) \log|\det W|~\mathrm{d}x\\
&= h(X) + \log|\det W|.
\end{align*}
$$

By the way, this notion of entropy, which applies to continuous random variables, is called *differential entropy* and usually denoted $h$ to distinguish from the entropy of discrete random variables, which has slightly different properties.